# Error in "file.tif" non-numeric argument to binary operator RASTER r

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I am trying to load a raster (.tif) in r. I get the following message `Error in "input"/"af_fa_9.tif" : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Here is my code

```
library(raster)
flow<-raster("input"/"af_fa_9_m.tif")
```

The file I am trying to load was downloaded from [USGS's](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/591f6d08e4b0ac16dbdde1c9) website.
It is called af_fa_9.zip

Anyone understand what is happening? I believe it's a NA data issue but I am not sure how to go around it.

Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
library(raster)
flow <- raster("input/af_fa_9_m.tif")
```

As-is you are trying to divide character string `input` with character string `af_fa_9_m.tif` to that you get

```
"a" / "b"
#Error in "a"/"b" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```